# How to copy member variables of the same name from different classes. (in JAVA)

Tags: java, copy, lombok

there are two classes below which are externally generated (can't be fixed by me)

```
public class ClassA{
 private Obj a;
 private Obj b;
 private Obj c;
 private Obj d;
}
```

```
@Builder
public class ClassB{
 private Obj a;
 private Obj b;
 private Obj c;
 private Obj d;
 private Obj e;
 private Obj f;
 ...(any other obj)
}
```

and I made bInstance like below.

```
ClassB bInstance = ClassB.builder().a(a).b(b).c(c).d(d).e(e).f(f).build();
```

And I want to get aInstance(ClassA) of bInstance and a,b,c,d with the same values (copying values with the same name).
How can I get the value I want?

Comment: are there any getters in ClassB?

Comment: B has no getter, but only A. @Stultuske

Comment: in that case, you can't get your values out of B, but you already have the values when you create your instance of B, so just re-use those.

Comment: Aha... There's no way to get it from b. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: There are probably ways, but B seems to be designed to not allow it

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways of doing it but if you want a general, automated way, the best lib that I've worked with is [MapStruct](https://mapstruct.org/). Please check the [reference documentation](https://mapstruct.org/documentation/dev/reference/html/) [for examples](https://mapstruct.org/documentation/dev/reference/html/#defining-mapper) on how to use it.

If you don't want or can't introduce a library and there are only a few situations where this copying between similar objects of different classes is necessary, you can create a class that does the work for you:

```
public class BeanMapper {
    public static ClassA from(ClassB b) {
        // assuming class A doesn't have a builder
        ClassA a = new ClassA();
        a.setA(b.getA());
        a.setB(b.getB());
        // set other properties...
        return a;
    }
}
```

Comment: there are no getters in B

Comment: Hum... then maybe you'll need to work with reflection to circumvent the `private` access, but I am not sure how to do that. Why doesn't the class have getters? Does `ClassA` also don't have getters? If it doesn't, then your example wouldn't work.

Comment: I have no idea, the OP told me there aren't any getters. in B, I know nothing of A. But why would A need getters?